# DLL for VBA.Collection

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, com-interop

I need to use a VBA.Collection class and I need to register a COM component in order to do that. I found msvbvm60.dll file on my computer and successfully registered it in my system. I am creating an instance of a class VBA.Collection, but I get an exception in that line of code:

```
VBA.Collection collection = new VBA.Collection();
```

The exception has the following description:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147221164   Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).   Source=mscorlib
>   ErrorCode=-2147221164

I used regedit.exe tool to search for a component with CLSID of {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB}, but haven't been able to find one. I suspect that there should be another .dll file that I should register, even though I can see with Object Browser in Visual Studio that reference to msvbvm60.dll gives me access to VBA namespace and Collection class within it.

It says on this web-page http://codeverge.com/asp.net.migrating-from-asp/using-vba.collection-object-in-net/577432 that the problem will go away if I instantiate VBA.CollectionClass . However, if I do so, I receive the following error and my code doesn't compile:

> Interop type 'VBA.CollectionClass' cannot be embedded. Use the
>   applicable interface instead

Have I registered the wrong COM component? Or is there anything I need to change in my C# code?

I also read on [How to create VBA.Collection() object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446755/how-to-create-vba-collection-object-in-c-sharp) that I need to create my own class based on VBA._Collection interface and not instantiate VBA.Collection class. I created the following class:

```
class MyCollection : VBA._Collection
{
    private Dictionary<object, object> _items = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    public void Add(ref object Item, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.OptionalAttribute]ref object Key, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.OptionalAttribute]ref object Before, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.OptionalAttribute]ref object After)
    {
        // Ignoring the Before and After params for simplicity
        _items.Add(Key, Item);
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _items.Count;
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public dynamic Item(ref object Index)
    {
        return _items[Index];
    }

    public void Remove(ref object Index)
    {
        _items.Remove(Index);
    }
}
```

I now instantiate MyCollection class with  `MyCollection collection = new MyCollection();`
I do not get an exception there anymore. However, I need to call a method GetIncidentCodes() of another COM component that returns an object of type VBA.Collection. If I use `collection = class1.GetIncidentCodes();`, then my program won't compile because an explicit cast is required. If I use `collection = (MyCollection) class1.GetIncidentCodes();`, then I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'PoliceDispatcherClient.MyCollection'. Instances of types that
>   represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent
>   COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the
>   underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of
>   the interface.

Should I cast the return value of `GetIncidentCodes()` into interface `VBA._Collection`? I am new to .NET, so I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: if you install the VB6 runtimes it should take care of registering the dll for you.

Comment: @Sorceri - I did download and install VB6 runtime from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192461 , but I still get the same error. I also have this warning now in my program: Processing COM reference "VBA" from path "C:\windows\SysWow64\MSVBVM60.DLL". Type library importer has encountered an interface not derived from IUnknown: '_HiddenInterface'. PoliceDispatcherClient (PoliceDispatcherClient\PoliceDispatcherClient)

Comment: First snippet cannot work.  Second snippet requires you to remove "Class" from the identifier name.  So just plain "VBA.Collection".  The applicable interface.  This will not solve your problem, it really isn't registered.

Comment: @HansPassant - yeah, I do not try instantiating VBA.CollectionClass. But I am not sure which .dll I need to register in order to get this to work. I did register MSVBVM60.DLL , but seems like it's not what I need...

Comment: I'll repeat, you cannot create a VBA.Collection, you'll *always* get the "Class not registered" error no matter what DLL you register.  The COM object is intentionally not registered, only VB6 or VBA code can create an instance of it.