# how to import VBA.dll in C# and register that dll in windows 10?

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com, com-interop

I need to use a VBA.Collection class and I need to register a COM component in order to do that. I have found VBA.dll and imported that dll in visual studio project .  I am creating an instance of a class VBA.Collection, but I get an exception in that line of code:

```
 VBA.Collection agentCollection = new VBA.Collection();
```

The exception has the following description:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I have searched a lot in the internet . For example I have seen the following link :

[1. DLL for VBA.Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816367/dll-for-vba-collection)

[2. Using VBA.Collection object in .NET](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.migrating-from-asp/using-vba.collection-object-in-net/577432)

[3. VBA.DLL dependency](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bbb5358-cc33-44e3-b7af-a7c05e87d734/vbadll-dependency?forum=clr)

But I have not found any solution . Please help me . How can I resolve this error ?

### **Update :**

[I have seen this URL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456690/6379197) I have used the code of accepted answer . But I am getting this error , "Cannot convert MyCollection to ref VBA.collections".

### **More Update :**

I have tried to register the VBA.dll by this syntax

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe VBA.dll
```

THe output of this command is :

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.6.79.0 
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.6.79.0 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Types registered successfully
```

Still I am getting this error :

```
But when I try to run my project I am getting this error : 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I do not know what is the reason .

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4446755/495455

Comment: I am getting this error using code in accepted answer . Cannot convert MyCollection to ref VBA.collections .