# Calling a VB6 DLL function with a complex User Defined Type (UDT) from C#

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, com-interop, user-defined-types

I am writing a C# application to call a third party VB6 DLL. I have added reference to the VB6 DLL in the References->COM tab.

A particular method in the DLL takes a VB6 UDT (User Defined Type) as a parameter.

This UDT is shown as a struct in the auto generated .NET wrapper for COM. The struct has lots of child UDTs / structs as well as members of type VBA.Collection (as shown by .NET metadata). It also has regular data types like string, short, double, int, etc.

I am initializing this struct in my C# code as:

```
udtEmployee udtEmpData = default(udtEmployee);
```

I also tried

```
udtEmpData = new udtEmployee();
```

If I do not initialize it using default or new, I am not able to compile my C# code, as the compiler complains about use of unassigned variable.

I need to pass this struct as reference. I am doing it like this:

```
clsEmployee.SetData(ref udtEmpData);
```

While calling this method of the VB6 DLL, I am getting error:

> Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

What is the reason and what is the solution?

Note, I can not change the VB6 DLL as I do not have its source code. I am using VS 2005.

EDIT 1:

Here is a complete background:

There is a locally developed ERP product, which supports add-on development using VB6. It has a configuration file, which specifies the names of add-on DLLs to be loaded. These addons are then displayed in a menu in the ERP application. On menu click, the ERP calls a function with the name StartAddOn() which should be present in the VB6 DLL.

I wanted to develop add-on in C#, so I developed a simple VB6 addon with a StartAddOn method, which in turn passes control to my .NET DLL.

The .NET DLL uses the business classes exposed by the ERP, and passes data objects to and fro. In the .NET DLL, I have added a COM reference to the DLL published by the ERP vendor.

So the architecture is like this:
ERP->VB6 AddOn with StartAddOn method->.NET DLL->uses COM DLL published by the ERP vendor and its data classes (structs / UDTs).

How can I debug the memory error?

Comment: Could it be that some of the sub-structs need 'new'ing as well as the highest level one?  I wish you luck, you've got a tough problem there.

Comment: I tried using new with each member struct, and also checked whether they in turn have other structs. Still I get the same error. What is the correct way to initialize the members of type VBA.Collection which is an interface? I tried using new VBA.CollectionClass. But I get another error: 
Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
---------------------------

Comment: you're calling a 32bit com dll from a 64 bit .net app?

Comment: I have checked my .NET DLL is also 32-bit. In the Configuration Manager, I have selected x86. I also tried with Any CPU. Both gave same error.

Comment: I suggest that wrap your .Net dll to COM. It will be: ERP->VB6 AddOn with StartAddOn method->Your .NET COM->COM DLL published by the ERP vendor.

    Or warp your .Net dll to exe. It will be ERP->VB6 AddOn with StartAddOn method->Your .NET exe (with parameters)->COM DLL published by the ERP vendor. 

    If you want to debug the .Net dll. Start ERP, attach your VS to the ERP process, then load your plugin.

Comment: I winder if you could generate the TLB for the ERP COM interface as that might help others see the issue and even try out some solutions.  It's one of those problems where you want to sit there with the debugger.

Comment: @neohope... how will wrapping the .NET dll to COM help? Ultimately the code has to be executed in the .NET runtime. Moreover, I do not know how to do this and dont think it will help. Regarding EXE, I made an EXE with command line parameter and it still gives the same issue. How do I attach the VS 2005 process to the ERP process. I have never done this before.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder, how do I generate the TLB for the ERP COM interface? They have published a dll which I have added as reference in my project.

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup and the `VB6 AddOn with StartAddOn method->.NET DLL` step in particular - how do you even do that if you're not already exposing your .NET dll as COM-visible? And if you are, why do you need the VB6 addon in the first place? You can directly create libraries in C# that will look like the ones VB6 creates.

Comment: Is it possible that the COM is looking for some other components like Adobe reader or Crystal Report or some thing like that which is not present but is required?

Comment: @AllSolutions Windows Task Manager->Process->Debug->select your vs project

Comment: Many programs will auto-allocate null inputs. Did you try setting your var to null and passing that in?

Comment: @GSerg, Yes my .NET DLL is COM-visible. But the reason I need the VB6 addon is that the StartAddOn method in VB6 can be inside a module, whereas in C#, it has to be inside a class.. the ERP has no way of knowing in which class is the StartAddOn method defined. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @Kumar C .. the COM is not looking for any other component like Adobe Reader or Crystal Report .. if I write the complete add-on in just VB6, it works. The issue is only when I am trying to use C# and pass the UDT to the methods exposed by the ERP's business classes.

Comment: So far, I do not have too many clues in which direction to proceed..

Comment: @AllSolutions Try defining a static class in C# and applying [StandardModuleAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.standardmoduleattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to it.

Comment: @AllSolutions you may have to use _Marshal.AllocHGlobal_ _Marshal.FreeHGlobal_ _Marshal.SizeOf_ along with _Marshal.PtrToStructure_. See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @robinet, I am not clear why I need to use AllocHGlobal, PtrToStructure, etc. The struct is auto generated by Visual Studio when I add a reference to the COM DLL. I am sorry but I have not understood enough in your reply why I need to use all these.

Comment: @GSerg, Thanks for the info on StandardModule attribute to simulate the VB6 module. I will try it later. But this will not help in the issue which I am facing, as my .NET code still has to use the VB6 DLLs published by the ERP vendor and I will run into the same issue.

Comment: @GSerg, I tried to call my .NET DLL directly from the ERP without the need for an intermediate VB6 DLL. But how do I register the .NET COM DLL as a VB6 DLL. I used to register the VB6 DLL using regsvr32. In my .NET project properties, I have checked "Register for COM Interop" which generates the TLB file for my .NET DLL. Do I register this TLB file using regsvr32? If I try to do, I get the error: "The module "xxx may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe."

Comment: In my .NET project, I have set the Build Configuration to Release and Platform is x86. My OS is 64-bit though. What should I do?

Comment: Do I need to install VB6 64-bit? Does VB6 even come in 64-bit?

Comment: @AllSolutions Forget about my previous comment, you are using COM interop, not P/Invoke. I still believe, though, that your problem is marshalling and/or shared memory between C# and VB6. If the UDT has VBA Collections as fieds you may need to have an implementation like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446755/how-to-create-vba-collection-object-in-c-sharp). Though, I'm not sure what will happen if VB6 attempts to modify the collection by adding/removing members (who would own the memory backing the collection??)

Comment: @robinet, Could it be that since the UDT is having members of type VBA.Collection and .NET treats collections as having 0-based index whereas VB6 treats it as 1-based? I got this info from one of the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323737

Comment: I tried creating a helper class in VB6 with a method to return a collection, and use this class in my .NET DLL to initialize all UDT members of type VBA.Collection, but still same issue persists :(

Comment: Ok. I am trying an alternate approach where I have written a function in VB6 to create and return the UDT. So the .NET code will call this VB6 DLL to create the UDT. But when I do this and run the .NET DLL from a test app, I get the error: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. What is the right way to return a UDT from a VB6 function to C#?

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to return a UDT from a VB6 function either in a class module or a code module to C#?

Answer (score 3):

What does the struct look like? It's been a while since I did any serious VB6 development, but one of the things I remember tripping me up sometimes when calling between languages was VB6's insistence on dword-aligning all of it's structures. So for example if you have some byte values mixed in the middle, it will insert padding so all the values align on an even 4 byte boundary. Consider the following:

```
Type MyType
    A As Long
    B As Byte
    C As Long
End Type
```

In memory, there will be 3 bytes of unused space between B and C. Of course if C# is not performing the same padding, it can throw your values off and cause all sorts of chaos.

With some compilers (such as C) it is possible to set a compiler switch to use this type of alignment. I don't know if C# has anything similar. If not, the solution is to insert some dummy fields of the appropriate size in to your struct on the C# size.

Here's an article which provides more information about how VB6 aligns UDTs:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3367/copymemory-and-arrays-proper-use/4/

Comment: Structure alignment can be manipulated with StructLayout attribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx

Comment: The UDT does not have any members of type Byte.

Comment: @Aloraman, the struct is auto generated by .NET when I add a reference to the COM DLL in my project.

Comment: Even though the UDT does not have byte data type, it has data types short, double & bool and also array declarations of each of these.

Comment: Anything does doesn't have a length that is an even multiple of 4 is suspect, including fixed length strings. You would think that if the interop layer was auto-gen'ing the struct it would take this in to account, but you never know. The comment by Aloraman about StructLayout is interesting. I wasn't aware of that attribute, but it sounds like the answer if this is the problem.

Comment: So what type of StructLayout should I use? And since .NET auto generates the struct definition, how can I modify that?

Comment: My guess would be Pack 4, but if the C# struct is defined in the interop layer, I'm not sure how you would specify it. Sorry I don't have more detail. My experience was between VB and C/C++ libraries. I still have some projects with interop to VB6, but they are the other way around (C#->VB) and we avoid structs completely.