# Call a VB6 function defined in a Code Module from C#

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, com-interop, winforms-interop

I have an ActiveX DLL created in VB6. In the VB6 DLL, I have defined a Public Function inside a Code Module. This function returns a User Defined Type (UDT).

When I add a reference to this DLL in my C# application, the Intellisense does not show this Module or the function.

But if I define a public function inside a VB6 class module, I am able to use it in C#.

My question is specifically whether I can call a VB6 function defined in a Code Module from C#.

I am using VS 2005, .NET 2.0.

Comment: You can't.  You can only call functions that are declared inside a Class and are not Shared.  Simplest approach is to just write that Class and have the function call the one in the Module.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "not Shared"? Writing a class is ok, but I get stuck because the class function is not able to return a UDT. So what is the solution?

Comment: If I try to return a UDT from a class' public function, I get the error: "Only public user defined types defined in public object modules can be used as parameters or return types for public procedures of class modules or as fields of public user defined types"

Comment: So is this a limitation of VB6, or is there any hack or workaround?

Comment: Pass it ByRef instead and make sure the UDT is declared Public.  Really rather best to avoid it, public UDTs have a knack for triggering build problems in VB6.  You can write yet another Class that has a property for each field in the UDT.

Comment: The UDT is Public. Pass it ByRef means what? You mean I should declare an instance of the UDT in C# and pass it by reference to the VB6 class function? If you mean this, then the C# compiler complains about use of unassigned variables. If I try to assign using new or default, I run into other issue which I have posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261070/calling-a-vb6-dll-function-with-a-complex-user-defined-type-udt-from-c-sharp, and it was to solve that issue in the first place that I wanted to instantiate a UDT in VB6 itself and return it to C# !

Comment: Actually I can not do away with the UDT. The real scenario is that the UDT is declared in a 3rd party library, and I need to instantiate it in VB6 and return to C#, to avoid the protected memory error I am getting when using it directly from C# (explained in the other thread).

Comment: I can declare the class method as Friend and it will be able to return the UDT, but this method will not be visible in C#.

Comment: A UDT is not "instantiated", it is just a variable.  You'd write Pubic Sub SomeName(ByRef retval As udtname) / retval = udtvariable / End Sub.  Where udtvariable is, say, in a Module or initialized by the class constructor.  udtname must appear in the type library, it should if you do it this way.

Comment: I understand, but I was referring to C# where the UDT is a struct. If I declare the struct in C# without initializing it, the compiler wont let the code  compile.

Comment: If I have to use ByRef in the VB6 class function, and I need to call this class function from C#, then I must declare a struct in C# and pass it using ref keyword right? If you try it, you will realize that you just cannot declare a struct and pass it by ref. You have to initialize it either using new or default keyword.

Comment: You can't get *out* in C#, the argument will show up as *ref*.  Don't sweat the small stuff, the point of a UDT/struct is that it is cheap.  So having to initialize it is nothing to fret about.  Use VB.NET if it really bothers you.

Comment: I am not sure if I have made myself clear to you. If you can read my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261070/calling-a-vb6-dll-function-with-a-complex-user-defined-type-udt-from-c-sharp, it will be clear.

Comment: You didn't.  Not documenting the UDT is kinda criminal, no wonder your previous question did not get any usable answers.  My original advice was to write a Class to wrap the UDT.  If you get AccessViolationExceptions then that was very good advice.

Comment: Can you pls respond to the question in the other link?

Comment: If I try to pass a UDT from a VB6 function defined in a Class to C# DLL, I am getting Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Comment: I wrote a class to wrap the UDT, but still I get Insufficient memory error in C#.