# 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) n using VBA.Collections

Tags: c#, vba, dll, vb6

I am using the collection class of VBA . I have imported the interop.VBA.dll in my project . Here is the screenshot :

[image]

But when I want to run the project , I am getting the following error :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Detail stacktrace :

```
[COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\ASP.NET Projects\SimpleWebPage\Default.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

I have checked that the vba.dll is 32 bit . My PC is 64 bit . So I have kept the dll to Syswow64 folder and registered it with regasm.exe . THe command for registering the dll is as follows :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe VBA.dll
```

But still I am getting the this error .

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

The line in which I am getting error is : 
       VBA.Collection agentCollection = new VBA.Collection();
How can I resolve this error . Any idea ?

Comment: What about changing build options from 'Any CPU' to 'x86'? Also since ASP.NET is used, probably 32-bit app support should activated too (in IIS of course). AFAIK, you can't create `VBA.Collection` directly since related COM object(s) intentionally unregistered in C# side (but VB6/VBA code can initialize that), but there is `VBA._Collection` interface which can be implemented for your own collection as workaround.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446755/how-to-create-vba-collection-object-in-c-sharp